# Initialize Component throws a null reference exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menu item in a large program that opens a new window. Nothing gets passed into it, it loads a calendar, 3 empty  text boxes, 3 labels, 2 buttons and an empty Crystal Report Viewer.

When its running the user clicks on the calendar and this automatically inserts the first and last dates of the selected month into 2 of the text boxes. One button loads a CR report with data from a DB, the other button prints the report.

This works fine on my system but the Initialize Component throws a null reference exception when deployed on a colleagues system. I cannot recreate the exception on my system.

Has anyone any ideas on where I should even start?

Updated

ERROR

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_PropertyWithConverter()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_BamlRecords()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Read()
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at KeyInScreen.RebatesReports.InitializeComponent()
   at KeyInScreen.RebatesReports..ctor()
   at KeyInScreen.Menu.FertiliserRebate_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="KeyInScreen.RebatesReports"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Fertiliser Rebates" WindowState="Maximized" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="700" 
    Width="1350">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FFEFEDDF">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Calendar x:Name="cDatePicker" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectedDatesChanged="cDatePicker_SelectedDatesChanged" />
    <Label Content="Start Date:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtStartDate" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Content="End Date:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtEndDate" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Supplier Number:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCustomerNumber" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TabIndex="1" />
    <Button x:Name="btnShowRport" Content="View Report" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Margin="0,0,10,0"  Click="btnShowRport_Click" IsDefault="True" />
    <Button x:Name="btnPrintReport" Content=" Print Report" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Click="btnPrintReport_Click" />
    <my:CrystalReportsViewer  x:Name="crReportViewer" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Height="656" Width="845" Margin="94,-7,62,12" ToggleSidePanel="None" Panel.ZIndex="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                              ShowPrintButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowSearchTextButton="False" ShowToggleSidePanelButton="True"
                              ShowToolbar="True" ShowNextPageButton="True" ShowGoToPageButton="True" ShowExportButton="False" 
                              ShowCopyButton="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ShowLogo="False" ShowPrevPageButton="True" 
                              ShowStatusbar="True" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by viewing the exception stack trace. Psychic debugging says that probably your window's Report Viewer (or some other heavyweight component) attempts to perform an iffy operation (e.g. connect to a data source) on construction, and it is this operation that fails on your colleague's machine (can't access a server, can't login with his credentials, etc).

Comment: Verify if all the components for Crystal are available.. Crystal Report Viewer seems to be a culprit

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the CR Viewer. I don't really understand the exception stack but I think the problem is with the WPF /XAMl

Comment: I would recommend cutting out various elements, rebuilding, and then run on the machine where it crashes. If it still crashes when you don't include CR, event handlers, etc, then you can narrow down the problem code. Alternatively, you may be able to deploy a debug build to get additional information about the issue.

Comment: When this happens on your colleagues machine and not yours then it could to do with the setups of .net framework or crystal report API on his/her machine. Did you BUILD your code on his/her machine and then tested this?

Comment: No I updated a program that was already installed, and when she tried to run the report it crashed. So instead of having one window that the user could enter the parameters on and view the report I split them up and now have two windows. We then found out that her machine runs and older version of Crystal Reports and so we are assuming that the old version didn't like the way the window was set for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the inner exception. When initialcomponent is called it can fire off other code which must be causing an exception. The inner exception should give you all the information you need. Note that it is possible that the inner exception will have an inner exception itself. Modify your app to write all these to a file or the clipboard or something.

Comment: What if the inner exception is null?

Answer (score 7):

Little late, but when you get a null reference exception like this, it can be misleading. The inner exception may be null (was in my case.)

The way I discovered the issue was to enable first chance exceptions in VS 2010.

Goto `Debug -> Exceptions`
then check all the boxes.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist in VS 2017, am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielMöller You'll want to use the Exception Settings window (Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings) or CTRL-ALT-E and then check everything. You'll only want this temporarily enabled for resolving your issue. You can then right-click and click Restore Defaults after.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem twice, and in both cases it was my lack of knowledge of patterns that are healthy for WPF programming.

In both cases, there wasn't an inner exception, and there was no code or whatsoever to follow and debug.

It happened that there was a `Binding` pointing to a `Path` that didn't exist in the `DataContext` object. It's very hard to find the problem, but I suggest to go looking for every `Binding` you have and the respective data context, having in mind that you might have a context coming from a parent upstream.

See this example (true case):

- I migrated an application from Windows Forms. Since I was working with a `Chart` I had to keep using some `System.Windows.Forms` components and their philosophy.
- I set the `DataContext` for the panel showing the chart programmatically with `MyChartPanel.DataContext = ChartControllerInstance`
- So far so good, the program worked pretty well, the bindings were all ok
- Later, I used the `XAML` way of adding a `DataContext` to the `Window`, for trying to have a viewmodel.
- Then the bug started.

What happened?

Since the chart data context was **not set in XAML**, but only via code, the **window data context** was propagated to all its children.

All those chart bindings (which in the first version didn't have a context at all) now had a context: the window view model, which didn't have anything needed for the chart.

The null reference appeared because those binding found a context, but not their path inside the context.

The solution? I had to explicitly use a `DataContext={Binding null}` in the chart panel, to prevent its bindings from searching inside the window context. This doesn't raise exceptions, and later in the code the chart context is set programmatically, and all works well.

I know this is a terrible bad practice, but I'm still a newbie in WPF and didn't figure out a better way yet.

Comment: +1 This was exactly my issue to. A bad binding for my data context. I used the wrong static resource name for the ViewModelLocator

Answer (score 0):

Issue disappeared when I rename/remove the old assemblies at GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL => GAC location for .NET framework 4.0 or higher) location.

Comment: GAC location for .NET framework 3.5 is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't call the `InitializeComponent();` within the constructor

EG

```
public partial class LogExaminer : Window
{
    public LogExaminer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    //comment out this to see the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin you can enable Compiled Bindings. In this case, binding issues will be caught by the compiler.

Consider enabling this feature for your projects, it's a time saver. I saw some plugins for WPF.