# Binding ListView Images from SQLite database, Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Person model:

```
 public class Person
 {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
 }
```

In my SQLite database I have pictures stored in the table. I'm trying to show the images in a ListView. So implemented a ImageConverter:

```
  public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        return retSource;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo     culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

In the Xaml code I'm trying to bind och convert the image like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="PersonListView">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="220">
                  <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

When I run the page I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't understand where it's wrong in my code. How can I view pictures from my database?

Comment: Where exactly does the exception occur? Check the call stack.

Comment: It occurs when I try to view the contentpage

Comment: I mean where in your code. The exception has a call stack.

Comment: When I open the call stack it points to:
Views.PersonsPage.InitializeComponent

Comment: Then take a look at the InnerException. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424236/initialize-component-throws-a-null-reference-exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your converter and let me know it works or not:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {                        
        return "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(value);;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo     culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```